# how to set webapplication.RightsMask via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

trying to change one of the rights assigned in RightsMask with Powershell on a SharePoint 2010 server.
$webApp=get-spwebapplication http://myWeb
$webApp.RightsMask

I want to be able to enable/disable flag: [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ViewListItems
but I can't figure out to how change just that one value - this is basically a bitmask field

Any Suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I'm clear -- by default a web application has the FullMask rights mask which allows all permissions to the web application. Are you trying to remove ViewListItems for all everything in the web application or do you have some other goal?

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem statet in your question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$webApp.RightsMask = $webApp.RightsMask -bor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ViewListItems;
```